# FINE logging org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection setAutoCommit = false

Tags: java, postgresql, wildfly-10, java.util.logging, postgresql-10

I was facing the issue with Postgres Driver which was 9.1-901.jdbc4 and my database server was Postgres 10.I was getting issue in bulk update so I tried to change the driver to version 42.2.5.Following is the dependency:-

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Its working fine now but I am getting infinite logs and I also do have Schedulars in my code:-

2019-06-04 06:48:33,358 FINE  [org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9)   setAutoCommit = false 
2019-06-04 06:48:33,359 FINE  [org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection] (DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-9)   setAutoCommit = true

How I disable these logs.I am using Wildfly 10 as application server.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have debug logging turned on. The simplest way would be with the web console or CLI. An example CLI command would look like:

```
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection:remove
```

Note you can use tab complete as you may not have that logger specifically added.

Comment: Thanks,I changed logging level for org.postgresql.jdbc from debug to INFO and now I am not getting the logs.